# Webmin dissapeared, but usermin is still there. Nothing is answering port 10000, but usermin is still answering port 20000

Tags: webmin

CentOS 6.10, installed with downloaded ./setup.sh from webmin.com on fresh OS install. webmin was working ok. Hadn't used it in several weeks. Then recently needed to use it... nothing was answering port 10000. service webmin status produced: [root@ns12]# service webmin status

> webmin: unrecognized service
> [root@ns12]#

All websites are running.
Didn't see anything in `error logs`, `miniserv.error.log`, `/var/log/messages`, etc.

Can I just reinstall webmin?, Or where should I start?

Comment: Why CentOS6?  That went EOL in November 2020.